# Rendering 2 partials in the same action, or an alternative to that

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form with various buttons and 2 selects like this:

```
|button1| |button2| |button3| |button4| |button5|

text fields
check boxes
etc

|select1|
somethings in the middle
|select2|
```

When i click on a button, an ajax call is made to the controller and 2 collections are populated.
How can i make the 2 selects be refreshed?
I have put the selects in 2 different partials, but there's no such thing as double render. I have tried to pass the different collections variables to the same partial like this:

```
render :partial => "list", :object => @list1, :as => list
render :partial => "list", :object => @list2, :as => list
```

And it didn't worked too...
Any sugestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably only want to have a single partial in this situation. For example, call it `_main_lists` (or what have you). Your controller would create the `@list1` and `@list2` collections, and pass them to `main_partial`. `main_partial` would simply then render your individual lists, exactly in the same manner as in your question.

Your AJAX request would get back both lists now, because it's getting back a partial that called 2 partials.

Another option you have is to return the lists as JSON and then to work with that.

Comment: Well, i hate that .js.erb crap. So i guess i'll try this way.

Comment: Ha yeah I usually steer clear of it as well. But yeah give it a shot and if it works for you be sure to mark the answer as the one that worked!